# when link a shared lib,How does CMake know whether to link an *.so file or a *.dll file

Tags: c++, cmake, find-package

i write a shared lib,named libTest.dll(windows) and libTest.so(ubuntu)，when a executable program link the shared lib.how did i write the cmakelists.txt，just give the lib name 'Test' ,then it can automatically link to the correct shared lib like boost.

I also really want to know why, when link to the boost library, only a key name is needed, then cmake can link to the correct platform's library.

Comment: To produce an executable, CMake has to know the target platform. And then it is aware of the rules for that platform.

Comment: ***boost library, only a key name is needed, then cmake can link to the correct platform's library***  In addition to the comment above, Boost has a finder module that helps with the per compiler naming: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) in your CMake folders you should have a `FindBoost.cmake` file. This is the finder module, if you want you can look at it's contents to see the operations it does for each compiler.